# How can I destroy the COOKIE of a deleted account from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I am currently developing a blog with PHP, MYSQL, it turns out that I have managed to make the system of accounts but currently I have an error, and is that I want to delete the information from the database to delete the open session.

Let me explain with an example: Let's say that user B has access to the blog by logging in with his account stored in the database, then for whatever reason this user was expelled and when deleting his account from the database, his session remains open thanks to the COOKIE that is in his browser and can continue to manipulate the blog.

So I don't know how to delete him from the database so that his session (COOKIE) expires too.

```
function loginUser($user){
    $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
    $_SESSION['admin'] = $user['admin'];
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'You have session active.';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';

    header('location: index.php');
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
ini_set('session.gc-maxlifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
    exit();
}

   if (isset($_POST['login-btn'])) {
        $errors = validateLogin($_POST);
        
        if(count($errors) === 0){
            $user = selectOne($table, ['email' => $_POST['email']]); 
            
            if ($user && password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password'])) {
            loginUser($user);
            
                } else {
                array_push($errors, 'Error.');
                } 
            
            }
        
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

}
```

Comment: You will have to check the database before giving an user access to the page content.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware sorry I didn't understand very well, the session works fine but when deleting a user from the users table in phpmyadmin, this user still has access to his account.

Comment: The user has still access to the account because you don't check whether the user is still present in the database. Therefore you have to check the database to see if the user is still present in the database before you continue and accept an user.

Comment: A cookie alone should never be enough to access an account. See: [Session hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware oh I understand, but how could I do that? sorry I'm new in php.

Comment: You basically check whether the user is present in the database. I'm not sure what more there is to explain. Your users have an unique (?) "id", so you could check whether that "id" is present in the database: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?;`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I added what you said but it didn't work very well, now it does detect users that are deleted but when I close the browser and reopen it, the session of a user exist closes.

Comment: I understand what you mean by: "the session of a user exist closes". Do you mean: "the session of an existing user closes"? Basically kicking user that are logged in, and present in the database, out? I don't think that has something to do with what I said.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware is that I do not understand very well and I do not know how to do it, for example that solution you said I think I put it wrong and that is why this is happening.

Comment: I'm sure you can work it out eventually. 